# How can i get more than 10 sub folders in Outlook folder using Graph api call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a folder in Outlook that has 20 sub folders , but if i use the following it only gets back the first 10.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/childFolders
```

I have also tried using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/?$top=250&$expand=childFolders
```

But still it only gets back the first 10.

Is there a way i can get back all the folders ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `$top` to your first query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/childFolders?$top=25
```

The `$top` in your second query will be ignored because the query returns the specific mail folder not a collection.

Comment: I ended up using , https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/childFolders?$top=25&$expand=childFolders  that worked